# FlowLayoutPanel does not wrap content

Tags: vb.net, winforms, flowlayoutpanel

I have a SplitContainer with Panel1 in the left side and **FlowLayoutPanel1** inside it. Likewise, there's a Pnael2 and **FlowLayoutPanel2** in the right side of the SplitContainer.

The settings are identical:
[image: Settings of Panels and FlowLayoutPanels]

This settings always works for me, but in this case, it works only in the left side. The **FlowLayoutPanel2** does not wrap it's contents (groupboxes containg another form with small graph), which **flows to the right beyond the form and screen**.

Any ideas, why this should happen?

Regards,

Oak

Answer (score 0, accepted):

OK, I finally found the reason of this problem: It was caused by the objects, which were inserted. When inserting the module, I accidentally left there this line of code:

```
NewLineChart.Dock = DockStyle.Fill
```

This is applied for inserting form into the module (GroupBox object), but should not be applied to the module itself...

Regards,

Oak